# Angular, json fetch list and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Ok, this is simple i think, but i havent tried this with json file. 
So the thing is that im now retrieving a whole json list like this json file: workers.json

```js
[{
  “workarea”: [“office”, “transport”, “IT”],
  “picture”: “some url”,
  “name”: “Mark janken”,
  “age”: 30,
  “location”: “holland”,
}]
```

And in my angular controller, im doing this right now and it works.

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('workers.json')
    .success(function(data){
    $scope.workers = data;
    });

});
```

But what if i should fetch a filter and list like this on the client side??
and have multiple filters, just like this:
/get-workers?location=:location

not sure how to aproach this.

Hope for some help or links. Thanks.

Comment: wait, is get-customers is diff from workers? If yes, please add code for it

Comment: Ups, sorry, no it is the same file, only one json file with data. I have just edited it now.

Comment: @user3503728 in order to correctly achieve this (meaning that you'll need to get some dynamic data from the URL you need to access router params. Check my answer for some code examples and feel free to ask anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this client side you need to introduce router in your project.

So after you introduce router (I prefer [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router))

You will have something like this in your states/routes configuration:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('workers', {
     url: '/workers/:myFilter',
     ...
  })
```

And then in your controller using $stateParams you can reach this parameter simply like `$stateParams.myFilter`

For example your controller will look like this:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', 
  function($scope, $http, filterFilter) {

      $http.get('workers.json')
        .success(function(data){
           $scope.workers = data;
           $scope.filteredWorkers = 
             filterFilter($scope.workers, {
               location:$stateParams.myFilter
           });
        });

});
```

Check more in the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), it's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

If it's getting the value from a server, that can be handles from the server side. Using the query string to filter the data on the server side.

But if you are geting the list from a json file, you have to filter the list after you have retrieved it

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, filterFilter) {

  $http.get('workers.json')
    .success(function(data){
       $scope.workers = data;
       $scope.filteredWorkers = filterFilter($scope.workers, {location:'holland'});
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes. Im only getting the list from a json file, no server, backend for this.

Comment: @user3503728 I've added a code sample to show how you can achieve this